# Nicely selecting and grouping by expressions, without using case-when

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

In MySQL, you can do nice things like

```
select bar > 2, count(*) from foo group by (bar > 2)
```

to get a result like

```
    bar > 2  count
    --------------
      0        12
      1        26
```

to indicate that there are 12 rows with bar <= 12 and 26 with bar > 12.

I would like to do the same on a DB2 database on an AS/400. It doesn't like expressions in the select or group by clause, but you can work around that using

```
select when (bar > 2) then 1 else 0 end, count(*) from foo 
  group by when (bar > 2) then 1 else 0 end
```

This works, but of course it is extremely ugly. My question is: is there a nicer way to do this, especially considering that I will probably be retrieving consolidated values over dozens of expressions this way? Perhaps there is even a standards-compliant way of doing this that I'm overlooking?

Edit: It turns out the case-when IS the standards-compliant way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think there is any fancy way, there doesn't even seem to be a way to cast from boolean to int directly.  CASE WHEN is standards compliant, and you can subquery it so as not to repeat the expression.

```
select bar2, count(*)
from
(
    select CASE when (bar > 2) then 1 else 0 end as bar2
    from foo
) SQ
group by bar2
```

Or with many fields

```
select bar2, foobar2, count(other1)
from
(
    select
        CASE when (bar > 2) then 1 else 0 end as bar2,
        other1,
        CASE when foobar=1 then 2 when foobar<10 then 1 else 0 end as foobar2
    from foo
) SQ
group by bar2, foobar2
```

SQL-92 text is available at http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt at time of this notes, the link itself was lifted from Wikipedia.  The spec on CASE statements cover 2 cases:

```
     <simple case> ::=
          CASE <case operand>
            <simple when clause>...
            [ <else clause> ]
          END

     <searched case> ::=
          CASE
            <searched when clause>...
            [ <else clause> ]
          END
```

Comment: "CASE WHEN is standards compliant" => I don't have a copy of the standard available, but my experiments since opening this question verify this: it works on Sqlite3, MySQL and the AS/400 DB2.